# Timestamp difference in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time, difference

I want to get the exact time difference between two php timestamps. 
& I m using this code

**CODE 1:**

```
   $d1=strtotime(date('H:i:s'));      //current time consider e.g 15:00:00
   $d2=strtotime('18:00:00');

   $all = round(($d2 - $d1) / 60);
   $d = floor ($all / 1440);
   $h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
   $m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
```

& if print this `$h & $m` - I get what exactly I m looking for ,
difference between two timestamps.

Now but I want to get `$d2` from my table ..

I have stored a timestamp in mysql table as datatype TIME .

as below

**CODE 2**

```
    $d1=strtotime(date('H:i:s'));      //current time consider e.g 15:00:00

$d2=strtotime($rows['showtime']);  //where $rows['showtime'] is the timestamp stored in mysql table. consider it as 18:00:00

$all = round(($d2 - $d1) / 60);
$d = floor ($all / 1440);
$h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
$m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
```

But when I print the `$h & $m` then i m not getting the values properly... 
Please any one help me to do so...

Code 1 works perfectly but when i try to execute Code2 it shows some garbage values not the values i m expecting.

please please please.

Comment: Show output of `var_dump($rows['showtime'])`.

Comment: Hi i m getting this as output    - string(8) "13:00:00"

Comment: Change `$all = round(($d2 - $d1) / 60);` to `$all = round(abs($d2 - $d1) / 60);`

Comment: hey thanks buddy & gr8 of you ... you solved it..... Its working fine now....

Comment: so what about writing an answer and marking the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the correct answer for this question

```
  $d1=strtotime(date('H:i:s'));      //current time consider e.g 15:00:00

  $d2=strtotime($rows['showtime']);  //where $rows['showtime'] is the timestamp stored in mysql table. consider it as 18:00:00

  $all = round(abs($d2 - $d1) / 60);
  $d = floor ($all / 1440);
  $h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
  $m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
```

USE abs() over there.